# How do I read performance counters in a .NET application without running as an administrator?

Tags: .net, windows, windows-services

How do I read performance counters in a .NET application without the application running as an administrator?

The application is a Windows Service. The account it will run under is known at install time, so in theory I could add any non-admin permissions to that account at that time.

Answer (score 2):

Can you add that account to the system's Performance Monitor Users group during install?

Reference:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2006/09/08/746900.aspx